# Splash Screen Retina 3.5

Tags: iphone, ios6, splash-screen

I'm not able to add splash screen for Retina device 3.5 in launch image, And while running with basic images its showing the following error,[image]

Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: it is showing no such file or directory as Default@2x.png..are you adding properly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Create another Default splash image with name `Default@2x.png` and store it in your project.

Just create this image with double size of original `Default.png` image...

Comment: just copy this image from finder and paste it in your project's any directory like Images name folder and the add this file from that directory and then try it

Comment: @Dev_iOS you did it?? here sometime you add just reference of some file after when you try to use that file and if that file removed with another project then system not find that image so you get this error .. once add it in your project directory and clean whole project and also reset the simulator or remove this app from device if u use device for testing... hope this helpful to you.. :)

Comment: i did that but now the warning removed, Error is still their

Comment: you clean up the xcode and also simulator?? also see this link may be its useful for you http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/two-splash-screen-display-in-iphone/..

Answer (score 0):

first check...in your project Directory...Default@2x.png is available or not....
 if yes then remove...and clean project...after then add once again...